# MySQL query joining 3 tables and counting

Tags: mysql, join, count

I've been stuck on this problem for far too long.
I have to merge 3 tables and do some counting of distinct values.
I have 3 tables
1.User_me
   profileId( String )
   responded( int 1 or 0)
2.Profiles
   profileId ( String )
   idLocation ( int )
3.lookup_location
   id ( int )
   location (String )

I can join User_me and Profiles ON User_me.profileId = Profiles.profileId
I can join Profiles and lookup_location ON Profiles.idLocation = lookup_location.id

Under Profiles I need to count the number of distinct values for idLocation where User_me.profileId = Profiles.profileId
I also need to count the number of Profiles.idLocation that have User_me.responded = 1

I have this:

```
SELECT lookup.location, count(*) as total
FROM User_me user
JOIN Profiles
  ON user.profileId= profiles.profileId
JOIN lookup_location lookup
  ON profiles.idLocation = lookup.id
GROUP BY profiles.idLocation
```

but I still need to have the column giving me the count where User_me.responded = 1
Something like:

```
SELECT lookup.location, count(*) as total, count(*) responded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can you a `case` statement in the `count` aggregate:

```
SELECT lookup.location, count(*) as total, 
    count(case when user.responded = 1 then 1 end) as responded
FROM User_me user
JOIN Profiles
  ON user.profileId= profiles.profileId
JOIN lookup_location lookup
  ON profiles.idLocation = lookup.id
GROUP BY profiles.idLocation
```

Since you're using `MySQL`, you can also use something like `sum(user.responded = 1)`.